# Method chose based on variable value

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

I'm writing a user's GUI and I want to create a method that will be create various number of buttons with previously defined names and actions. But I have no idea how to write method selection which is based on variable value. Google gives no useful information about it. Can anyone help with this or it's just impossible?

Here is some code example:

```
    String[] actions={"testAction1","testAction2","testAction3"};
    defaultDialogWindow(actions,"test1", "test2", "test3");

    void defaultDialogWindow(String[] actions, String... bNames){
          double layoutX = 25;
          double spacing = 15;
          final Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
          dialogStage.initOwner(stage);
          dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);   
          dialogStage.setFullScreen(false);
          dialogStage.setResizable(false);
          dialogStage.setHeight(100);
          dialogStage.setWidth(bNames.length*100+(bNames.length-1)*spacing+2*layoutX+5);
          dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(buttonBuilder(actions,spacing,layoutX,bNames)));
          dialogStage.show();  
    }

    HBox buttonBuilder(String[] actions, double spacing,double layoutX,String... bNames){
          HBox lBar = new HBox(10);
          final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty menuWidthProperty = lBar.widthProperty();
          lBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
          lBar.setLayoutX(layoutX);
          lBar.setSpacing(spacing);
          for(String text : bNames){
              Button newButton = new Button();
              newButton.setText(text);
              newButton.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", 22));
              newButton.prefWidthProperty().set(100);
              newButton.prefHeightProperty().set(50);
              newButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(ActionEvent paramT) {

                      **HERE MUST BE ACTION CALL BASED ON bNames VALUE**

                      System.out.println("button pressed");
                  }
              });
              lBar.getChildren().add(newButton);
          }
          System.out.println(lBar.prefWidth(-1));
          return lBar;
      }

      void testAction1(){
          System.out.println("this is test action one");
      }

      void testAction2(){
          System.out.println("this is test action two");
      }

      void testAction3(){
          System.out.println("this is test action three");
      }**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HashMap:

```
Map<String, Runnable> actions2methods = new HashMap<>;
actions2methods.put("Action1", new Runnable { public void run() { testAction1(); }));
```

You can even make this easier if your actions would be `Runnable` instead of methods from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionEvent` to communicate which action was taken. This defaults to the label of the button but can also be set (without affecting the label) using `Button.setActionCommand()`.

```
 newButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent paramT) {
         String actionCmd = paramT.getActionCommand();
         if (actionCmd.equals("A")) {
             doA();
         } else if (actionCmd.equals("B")) {
             doB();
         }
         System.out.println("button pressed");
     }
 });
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html